# Finding a varchar value that matches another value in a table of 200,000 records

Tags: mysql

I have a table called USERS that has several fields, including one called 'postal' of type 'varchar' (6).

Then I have another table called POSTALS that only has one column: 'postal' of type 'varchar' (6).
This POSTALS table has about 200,000 records.

I need to get all records from the USERS table where the 'postal' in that table matches a 'postal' in the POSTALS table.

I tried the obvious basic query:

```
SELECT users.user_id, users.user_fname, user_lname 
                FROM users, postals 
                WHERE replace(user_postal , ' ','') = postals.postal
```

But this query never completes. It always times out.I can see this would be a very resource intensive query as it compares every value of 'users' (which has about 250,000 rows) with every value of 'postals' (which has almost 200,000 rows).

Any other more streamlined way of doing this comparison?
Thanks.

Comment: Maybe do a TRIM on that column and try to JOIN them after.Split the load.

Comment: Do you need `replace`?  Using it will remove any index on that field in your `users` table.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT u.user_id, u.user_fname, u.user_lname 
FROM users u WHERE EXISTS (SELECT DISTINCT postal FROM postals WHERE postal = u.postal)
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that both are `varchar(6)`, why are you replacing spaces?

```
SELECT u.user_id, u.user_fname, u.user_lname 
FROM users u join
     postals p
     on u.user_post = p.postal;
```

To make this run faster, create an index on the `postals` table:

```
create index postals_postal on postals(postal);
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the call to `replace` isn't obvious from your question. Is there a reason you need to strip all spaces? This function call on every comparison (as well as the potential lack of indexes) would be what is killing your query.

First thing is to check that there is an index on the `postal` field in both tables.